# I'm trying to understand JWT-based authorization between applications

Tags: jwt

I'm trying to understand JWT-based authorization between applications, and it's a bit unclear to me. I have 2 applications: app1 is responsible for user authorization. Upon logging into app1, I receive a JWT token. When I want to retrieve resources from app2, for example, /api/get-data, I send the token in the header. App2 checks the validity of the format (header, payload, and signature), as well as its expiration date. If everything is okay, it sends a request to app1/api/token/verificate to verify the token. Upon receiving confirmation that the token exists, I receive resources from /api/get-data. Do I understand this correctly? Did I miss anything? Is signature verification of the token still needed here?

Comment: Typically, as the token the valid time of the token is relatively short and it is signed by app1 with a secret key only known to app1, in app2 you only need to check if the signature is valid. There is no need for a request from app2 to app1

Comment: @derpirscher It is better to keep the public key of app1 permanently in app2 or to fetch it every time?

Comment: I wouldn't fetch it every time, but I'd create some possibility to revoke a key